# Oracle - Selecting employees which were hired in the last 20 years

Tags: sql, oracle

I cannot use months_between, only playing with DATEs is allowed, so I got this:

```
select * from emp
where ((SYSDATE- hiredate)/(365+1/4-1/100+1/400)) >= ((SYSDATE/(365+1/4-1/100+1/400))-20);
```

I dont understand why i get error in

```
(SYSDATE/(365+1/4-1/100+1/400))-20
```

saying it is an invalid datatype "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s" when

```
(SYSDATE-hiredate)/(365+1/4-1/100+1/400)
```

is working properly with no error, WTF?

PS: an example of using (365+1/4-1/100+1/400) is with birth date, for more precision:

```
((SYSDATE- birth_date)/(365+1/4-1/100+1/400)) >=18
```

Comment: Maybe using `hiredate >= add_months(sysdate, -12 * 20)` or intervals would be more clear.

Comment: I would try somethinh like select to_number (sysdate-to_date('19940610','yyyymmdd'))/7305 from dual; then compare it (Note: 20 years would always have fixed number of days )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sysdate` retuns the current date and time.

In your second test case as below, you are subtracting two dates which returns
numeric value indicating the number of days between the two dates and so calculation (division was made possible).

```
(SYSDATE-hiredate)/(365+1/4-1/100+1/400)
```

In your first test case as below, you are directly trying to divide a date type value.
you cannot divide a date datatype in oracle. Instead you can add any value say x (`sysdate +x`), it means you are adding x days to the date value.

```
(SYSDATE/(365+1/4-1/100+1/400))-5
```

In case, you want to convert the `sysdate` to number you can try like below

```
select to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmddhh24miss')) from dual;
```

Which will return you DATE+TIME like `20140608165750` for today.

(OR)

```
select to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd')) from dual;
```

Result will be `20140608` (only the DATE part)

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle on subtracting two `Date` datatypes you'll get a `Number` datatype.
From Oracle docs: [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50990)

So this part of your query
 `((SYSDATE- birth_date)/(365+1/4-1/100+1/400)) >=18` returns a number, whereas

In this statement
 `(SYSDATE/(365+1/4-1/100+1/400))-5` sysdate is still taken as a date dataype which is why you're getting the error. You can explicitly use `to_number` to convert sysdate into number.

Edit: Try this `((to_number(to_char(SYSDATE,'DDMMYYYY'))/(365+1/4-1/100+1/400))-5)` to convert your sysdate date dataype into number datatype. So, your select query should look like this

```
select * from emp
where ((SYSDATE- hiredate)/(365+1/4-1/100+1/400)) >= ((to_number(to_char(SYSDATE,'DDMMYYYY'))/(365+1/4-1/100+1/400))-5);
```

Comment: select to_number(sysdate) from dual; getting invalid number rerror :S